# Unable to connect to hive using python using impyla/dbapi.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I am trying to connect to hive[with default derby db] using python:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect( host='localhost', port=10000)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM employee')
print cursor.description  # prints the result set's schema
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

but I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hivetest_b.py", line 2, in <module>
    conn = connect( host='localhost', port=10000)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/dbapi.py", line 147, in connect
    auth_mechanism=auth_mechanism)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 758, in connect
    transport.open()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 149, in open
    return self.__trans.open()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 101, in open
    message=message)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:10000
```

entry in my /etc/hosts is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I am using default hive-site.xml and defult derby database for running my hive. When I run hive through shell it shows me that table:

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
test
test_db
Time taken: 0.937 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> show tables;
OK
employee
Time taken: 0.054 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> describe employee;
OK
empname                 string
age                     int
gender                  string
income                  float
department              string
dept                    string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

dept                    string
Time taken: 0.451 seconds, Fetched: 11 row(s)
```

I am not sure what exactly am I missing here. Any quick references/pointers would be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 0):

You can check and validate the port with:

```
hive> set hive.server2.thrift.port;
```

And try `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` as your host for the connection.

Comment: Thanks for responding Darius. my thrift port is 10000 and I also tried using 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 but of no luck. :-(